# Can't parse XML data with C#

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have been trying to extract one value from a XML file, and then store it on the same file but in another node, I tried all the examples i've found on the net, read XPath Syntax documentation like hell and still can't get it to work.

I must take the `<Documento ID="F60T33">` ID Value (which may vary) and copy it into `<Reference URI="#F60T33">`.

But I can't even do that if I can't manage to parse the lines, most of times node/variables/"", or I get an "object reference not established as object instance error".

Here's the code:

```
    // Create a new XML document.
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        // Load an XML file into the XmlDocument object.
        xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
        xmlDoc.Load(pfile);

        //TEST !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! PROBLEMA

        XmlNodeList Documentos = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("//Documento");
        XmlNodeList DatosDocumento = ((XmlElement)Documentos[0]).GetElementsByTagName("ID");

        foreach (XmlElement nodo in DatosDocumento)
        {

            int I = 0;

            XmlNodeList ID = nodo.GetElementsByTagName("ID");
            Console.WriteLine("Elemento nombre ... {0}}", ID[i].InnerText);

        }

        //
        XmlNodeList nodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("EnvioDTE");
        XmlNode nodesimple = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("EnvioDTE");
        Console.WriteLine("Lista Nodos: " + nodes.Count);
        Console.WriteLine("Nodo Simple: " + nodesimple.InnerText);
        foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
        {
            string id = node.Attributes["ID"].InnerText;
            Console.WriteLine(id);

        }
```

I am almost certain the problem is on the XPath Syntax, but I can't get it to work.

Sadly I can't use XDocument as im using .NET 3.5 for this task, I would really appreciate some help on this, by behand apologize my bad english

As the XML file is too big, I'll put it here on this URL
http://puu.sh/bVNDc/31e4da5a26.xml

Comment: Actually, you _can_ use [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.90).aspx), as it is available in .NET 3.5.

Comment: `.GetElementsByTagName("ID");` Does not work because that method looks for `<ID>` however no such element exists in the XML.  You've confused elements with attributes.  The second for foreach does not work because the EnvioDTE element does not have an ID attribute.  You need to select the SetDTE element first if you are trying to access its ID attribute.

Comment: LINQ to XML also exists in .NET 3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can get your references right for using System.Linq.XDocument you can do:

```
string idValue = xDocument.XPathSelectElement("//EnvioDTE/SetDTE")
     .Attributes().SingleOrDefault(a => a.Name == "ID").Value;
```

Comment: SingleOrDefault may return a null, and then you'd get a NullReferenceException when you hit "Value"

I believe you need to set a reference, test for null, then get the value property on your reference.

Or did I miss something?

Comment: @WesleyLong Yes, it is good to point that out. You'd want to break it up with some conditionals depending on what you preconditions are and are not. It'd all fall apart if the XML he gave isn't the actual XML he intends to use this code on. It depends on the schema, whether those elements are required or optional. My answer isn't intended to cover all the contingencies from bad XML structure to file permissions.